# Is there a way to put a CSS file after the App_Theme files

Tags: asp.net, app-themes

Is there a way to put my custom CSS file outside of the App_Themes folder AFTER all the other CSS files get loaded by the Skin/App_Themes folder?

When the application runs, the App_Themes files are always placed last. But I have a custom CSS file I want to load last, that is referenced from an external URL and is not in the App_Themes folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just add a css include tag wherever you want it?

Comment: @JonathanWood, What do you mean?  I put the link tag with the css file pointing to my external file.  But when the .Net application runs,  my file gets put before the files that the application injects into the head tag that are in the App_Themes folder. Even if I put my CSS file immediately before the ending head tag. I want mine to be the last on the list because they will be overrides for the other CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `HtmlLink` control manually to the page in an event that runs after the themes CSS are added. The `Page_PreRender` event runs last before the page is shown.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myCss = new HtmlLink();
    myCss.Href = "http://www.example.com/scripts/myCss.css";
    myCss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    myCss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");

    // Add the css reference at the end of the head after everything else
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(myCss);
}
```

Comment: So not as straight forward as just adding it to the  .master page or wrapping it in a simple asp tag and having it come last.  My issue is, the project is already compiled.  I don't know if I would want to add this to the .master page inline. But I guess I could.